# Duda con ejercicio de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dudas sobre cómo conseguir hacer este ejercicio de python:

> Utilizando el fichero notas.csv, realiza un programa en python que lea los datos de ese fichero y construya la siguiente estructura:
>
> ```
>   alumnos = [ {"nombre":"Daniel", "apellidos":"Fustero López", "curso": "1A",
>     "notas":{"FH":3,"LM":4,"ISO":5,"FOL":6,"PAR":7,"SGBG":6}},
>          {"nombre":"Rafaela", ... }
>        ,...]
> ```
>
> Crea un programa que te de muestre un menú y puedas elegir una de estas opciones:
>
> - Muestra el listado de los alumnos con la nota media que han sacado. Utiliza una función para realizar el cálculo de la nota media.
> - Pide un curso y una asignatura y muestre una lista de los alumnos de ese curso con las notas en esa asignatura.
> - Pide un curso y muestre el porcentaje de aprobados por cada asignatura.
> - Pide un curso, y crea un fichero nombredelcurso.txt con los alumnos y la nota media.

De momento tengo este código pero no hay manera de sacarlo de ninguna de las maneras. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

```
def recorrerLista():
listaNotas = []
primera = True
with open("notas.csv", "r") as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        if primera:
            primera = False
            continue
        else:
            alumnos = dict ()
            notas = dict ()
            listaLinea = linea.split(",")
            alumnos['Apellido'] = listaLinea [0]
            alumnos['Nombre'] = listaLinea [1]
            alumnos['Curso'] = listaLinea [2]
            notas['FH'] = listaLinea [3]
            notas['LM'] = listaLinea [4]
            notas['ISO'] = listaLinea [5]
            notas['FOL'] = listaLinea [6]
            notas['PAR'] = listaLinea [7]
            notas['SGBD'] = listaLinea [8]
            alumnos['notas'] = notas
            listaNotas.append (alumnos)
print (listaNotas)
recorrerLista()
```

Estoy atascado completamente en todo, ya no sé cómo seguir el programa. Éste es el fichero .CSV en sí:

```
Nombre,Apellidos,Curso,FH,LM,ISO,FOL,PAR,SGBD
ACEVEDO JHONG, DANIE,1C,2,0,6,1,1,8
ALCALÃ NEGRÃ“N, CHRISTIAN NELSO,1C,3,0,6,10,9,9 
ALMORA HERNANDEZ, RAUL EDUARD,1D,4,3,1,3,3,8
```

Comment: Hola Nikoboko, ¿Cuál es el problema concreto o en que punto estás atascado? ¿Qué estructura tiene el csv? Si muestras algunas líneas del csv (incluida cabecera) haces más fácil la tarea a quien quiera ayudarte. ¿Puedes usar módulos importados desde la biblioteca estándar? Lo digo porque esto es bastante simple si se usa el módulo `csv` y `DictReader`/`DictWriter`.

Comment: Hola Nikoboko, tal y como está redactada la publicación, la pregunta es demasiado amplia. Los problemas sin un enunciado concreto no son de ayuda a otros usuarios y no estamos aquí para hacer la tarea a nadie. No puedes estar atascado completamente en todo, ¿qué es lo que no sabes hacer? ¿cuál es el paso/dificultad que te impide avanzar? Concreta el problema que estás teniendo, busca información sobre lo que dice FJSevilla en su comentario y edita la pregunta para añadir esos detalles. Lee [ask] para más información y consejos, y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, como te han comentado otros compañeros es demasiado ambigua la pregunta y deberías ser más conciso en el problema que tienes. De todas formas, te he dejado un pequeño código que te puede servir de referencia. Lógicamente no están todas las opciones que planteas.... Espero pueda serte de ayuda.

```
def leerFicheroCsv():
  f=open('alumnos.csv', 'r')
  try:
    return csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
  except csv.Error as e:
    print ('Error al abrir fichero %s, error: %s' % (filename, e))
    time.sleep(2)


def notaMediaAlumnos():
    sum=0
    cont=0
    for row in leerFicheroCsv():
       cont+=1
       sum+=int(row['FH'])+int(row['LM'])+int(row['ISO'])+int(row['FOL'])+int(row['PAR'])+int(row['SGBD'])

print ("La nota media de los alumnos es: ", round(sum/cont/6, 2))
time.sleep(2)


def notaAsignaturaCurso(sign, curs):
    encontrado=False
    for row in leerFicheroCsv():
        try:
        if curs==row['Curso']:
            print ("%s%s tiene una nota de %s en la asignatura"  % (row['Nombre'], row['Apellidos'], row[sign]))
            time.sleep(1)
            encontrado=True
        except:
            print ("La asignatura %s no existe en el fichero CSV" % sign)
            time.sleep(3)
            encontrado=True
            break

if not encontrado:
    print ("El curso %s no existe en el fichero CSV" % curs)
    time.sleep(3)


def principal():

   opcion='0'

   while opcion!='3':
    print ("""
    Selecione una de las siguientes opciones: 
    1. Nota media de cada alumno
    2. Nota por asignatura y curso
    3. Salir del programa""")

    opcion=input("    Opción: ")

    if opcion=='1':
        notaMediaAlumnos()
    elif opcion=='2':
        asig=input("Introduzca Asignatura: ")
        curso=input("Introduzca Curso: ")
        notaAsignaturaCurso(asig, curso)
    elif opcion=='3':
        print ("Goodbye!!!")
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print ("Opción inválida. Vuelva a introducir opción...")
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    principal()
```